# Subclassing std::chrono::duration

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have a piece of code where `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::milli>` is subclassed, and used to create a `std::chrono::time_point`, like so:

```cpp
#include <chrono>

class my_duration : public std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::milli>
{ /* snip */ };

int main() 
{
    typedef std::chrono::time_point< std::chrono::system_clock, my_duration > my_time_point;
    my_time_point t( my_duration{} );
    //....
}
```

This was seemingly compiling and working fine when using GCC < 10. However, when using GCC 10, a static assertion in std::chrono::time_point will fail with:

> /opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/11.0.0/chrono:764:37: error: static
>   assertion failed: duration must be a specialization of
>   std::chrono::duration

This can be seen at the following link, which also demonstrates that clang gives the same error: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CQw6fWt4kZ1xYdet

In std::chrono, the failing assert is due to the `__is_duration` structs used by `time_point`:

```cpp
template<typename _Tp>
  struct __is_duration
  : std::false_type
  { };

template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
  struct __is_duration<duration<_Rep, _Period>>
  : std::true_type
  { };

//... further down, in time_point: 
static_assert(__is_duration<_Dur>::value,
    "duration must be a specialization of std::chrono::duration");
```

My understanding of it is that `__is_duration<my_duration>` will be an `std::false_type` causing the static assert to fail.

So, my question is: does this mean it isn't possible to subclass std::chrono::duration and use the derived class with time_point? Or is there some trick that will allow the duration subclass to pass the static assertion?

Comment: Perhaps you can obtain the customization you desire by writing a custom representation?  `using my_duration = std::chrono::duration<custom_rep, std::milli>;`

Comment: Thank you, Howard. My challenge is that I already have a lot of code relying on things like `someDuration.getSeconds()` (where getSeconds is a method of the subclass my_duration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::time_point` has always required that the duration type be a specialization of `std::duration`. If it isn't, then the program is ill-formed (aka: compile error). This may just be the first time GCC implemented that requirement.

Deriving from `duration` doesn't really serve any useful purpose.

Comment: Strong type aliases can be very desirable, though I concede it doesn't seem like the end of the world to drop that here. The alternative is wrapping the cr@p out of it...

Comment: (standard wording if you want it: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.point#2)

Comment: Ill-formed does not mandate a compiler _error_; it requires _a diagnostic_, which can be anything that the compiler documentation says it is. The standard does not require that compilers refuse to compile ill-formed code; having issued a diagnostic, the compiler is free to do anything with the program, including producing an executable with an implementation-specific interpretation of the ill-formed code.

Comment: @PeteBecker: For all *useful* purposes, ill-formed with a diagnostic is implemented nearly universally as a compile error of some form. Different compiler switches may turn some subset of them into warnings (or some compilers may make some of them warnings by default) but generally speaking, they're compile errors.

Comment: There are many **language extensions** that come from implementation-specific interpretations of ill-formed code. `int n = 3; int m[n];` in g++ is one notorious example.

Comment: _"This may just be the first time GCC implemented that requirement."_ Yes, I added the check recently, we failed to enforce the rule previousy (and in this case it would be tricky to issue a warning rather than an error, for not much benefit).

Comment: @PeteBecker: And yet, that's in violation of the standard because no diagnostic is given for it.

Comment: <shrug> -- I'll bet with the right set of compiler flags you'd get a warning. But, yes, if it doesn't issue a diagnostic, it doesn't conform to the language definition.

Comment: `-Wpedantic` or `-Wvla`

Comment: Thank you all for the useful input. It seems MSVC also does not warn about this.